# How to get data from partial in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have
ASP.NET MVC Form in popup with some controls and partial (data grid) with his own Model.
here is  popup:

```
<div id="AddEditDialog" class="none">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Templates", new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "AddEditPlaceHolder",
            OnSuccess = "OnSaveSuccess",
            HttpMethod = "Post"
        }))
    {
    <div>
        <div id="AddEditPlaceHolder"></div>
        <div id="PopupButtons" class="btn-holder-centered">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" name="SaveButton" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="SaveCancelButton" id="CancelEditHandler" />
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

here is form which I render in AddEditPlaceHolder via js:

```
@model TemplatesViewModel   
<div class="form-field-plain overflow">
    <div class="forRow narRow float-left">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Revocable)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Revocable)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-field-plain overflow">
    <div class="forRow narRow float-left">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.HtmlTemplate)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.HtmlTemplate)
    </div>
</div>

@Html.Partial("_VariablesGridView", Model.Variables)
```

_VariablesGridView.cshtml:

```
@model List<TemplateVariableViewModel>

<table id="TemplateVariablesGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Tag/Code</td>
            <td>Prompt</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var i in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox("txtTag", @i.Tag, new {})
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox("txtPrompt", @i.Prompt, new { })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.First(s => s.Id == @i.Id).Id)
                    <label class="delete-variable">delete</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" name="btnAddTemplateVariable" value="add new variable"/>
<br />
```

My problem is :
in Controller 'save form' method public ActionResult Save(TemplateViewModel model)
my model contains all data from form but TemplateViewModel.Variables is empty

Is there any way to fill it in there?

Models:

```
public class TemplateViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string HtmlTemplate { get; set; }      
    public List<TemplateVariableViewModel> Variables { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateVariableViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string Prompt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the markup from _ConsentVariablesGridView.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because the ASP.Net MVC binding is not putting these fields in context, have a look at your field names delivered to the browser, what is txtTag prefixed by when it gets to the browser and what is is after you do the following:

```
@Html.Partial("_VariablesGridView", Model)
```

_VariablesGridView.cshtml:

```
@model TemplatesViewModel
...
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Variables.Count; i++)
    @Html.TextBox("txtTag", @Model.Variables[i].Tag, new {})
```

Forgive me if this fails miserably (again), I'm shooting from the hip.

Comment: It look sensible, let me try it

Comment: Unfortunately - it's not a solution. I've fixed field naming in a "view" but TemplateViewModel.Variables is still empty on submit

Comment: Try the updated for loop. After this I will accept my miserable failure for what it is :)

Comment: I've found solution. Give me a minute to describe it :). Without going into too much detail - I should use TemplateEditor instead Partial

Comment: .. and - yes, I have to use for for iterating throu it to track index

Comment: Aha, nicely done. This is why I couldn't spot the problem. I always use EditorTemplates, and never use partials. I know some people have success with them in iterative form scenarios such as these, but I am an EditorTemplate junkie. Glad you're sorted and sorry I couldn't be of more direct help.